# NGINX + Rails: serving static directory, index.html, AND all other routes to rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

So NGINX is working great for my rails app - but would love a little help getting the config correct for a mixed static / dynamic environment. It's an API, so basically:

1. Serve public/index.html since it's silly to write a controller for a single static html page to say "welcome to the API".
2. Serve the docs from /app/doc on blah.com/doc
3. Serve all other requests to the proxy.

Right now I know my locations / try_files, etc are squashing each other, but i've tried a pile of permutations and can't get them all working at once. :)

```
upstream ss-api {   server unix:/tmp/ss-api.socket fail_timeout=0; }

server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api_access.log;

    location {
        root /home/deployer/apps/api/current/public;
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @ss-api;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        root /home/deployer/apps/ss-api/current/doc;
    }

    location @ss-api {
        proxy_pass  http://ss-api;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size       4G;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```